# get a controller and method from url?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, routes

ok i have a url from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

lets say it give us a url

```
http://localhost/controller/method
```

i have tried something like

```
explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])
```

and it gave us like

```
array
  0 => string '' (length=0)
  1 => string 'controller' (length=10)
  2 => string 'method' (length=6)
```

what is the best way to get the controller or method ? or removeing the 0 in the array ? ( first array ) ?

so it will be like

```
$controller = 'controller';
$method = 'method';
```

from above inputs.
maybe about list ? still no clue using list().

edit heres what ive done so far

```
    $this->url = str_replace(config('foldertoscript'), NULL, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $hello = explode('/',$this->url);var_dump($hello);
    array_shift($hello);
    list($controller,$method) = $hello;
    var_dump($hello,$controller);
```

in a class

Thanks for looking in.

Adam Ramadhan

Comment: $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] does not contain the host name in you case it just contain controller/method. so no worries. I am sure you are doing something wrong

Comment: list() operator is exactly for that purpose. **However** I'd use not explode but regexp to make a **validation** at once.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the first element of an array, you can use `array_shift()`.

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` gives you the url without the "http://www.yoursite.com".

You can use something like this

```
<?php
function curPageURL() {
 $pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
 $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
}

echo curPageURL();
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use array_shift to remove the first array item.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php

Example:

```
$your_array = array_shift($your_array);
$controller = $your_array[0];
$method = $your_array[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

For the same matter I use url_rewriting.

I have a rule that says ^([a-zA-Z0-0-_\/.]+)$ index.php?url=$1 
(this is not a copy paste from my code, but you get the idea)
then if you say $_URL = $_REQUEST["url"];

$directive = explode("/",$_URL);

you will get what you need, as for the parameters you could say module/method/id/1/data/2

you have to take care of your parameters and it works if you use the GET method for

navigation only(as it should be used). Also makes the stuff much safer as no one can send SQL

injections via get or any "smart" directives.